# OpenCart Journal2 admin panel not loads

Tags: php, https, apache2, opencart

After changing from HTTP to HTTPS in my OpenCart installation with Journal2 theme/plugin I have problem - admin panel for Journal2 not loads, showing "Loading..." state and that's all.

```
Journal2 version = 2.13
OpenCart version = 2.3.0.2
Current stack: PHP 7 + Apache2 + MySQL
```

Also adding screenshot.

What is broken? I have updated website url from http:// to https:// in admin panel, also updated variables in

```
config.php
```

and

```
/admin/config.php
```

files. Maybe problems with caching?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the two config files for correct configuration of Data Base and file folders.

Also u need to check the file in system/library/url.php

on that,

```
public function link($route, $args = '', $secure = false) {
    if ($this->ssl && $secure) {
        $url = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '/.\\') . '/index.php?route=' . $route;
    } else {
        $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '/.\\') . '/index.php?route=' . $route;
    }

    if ($args) {
        if (is_array($args)) {
            $url .= '&amp;' . http_build_query($args);
        } else {
            $url .= str_replace('&', '&amp;', '&' . ltrim($args, '&'));
        }
    }

    foreach ($this->rewrite as $rewrite) {
        $url = $rewrite->rewrite($url);
    }

    return $url;
}
```

Hope It will helps you.

Comment: I have re-checked both config files (in admin and in the root folders), both are correct. Path for the root I took from phpinfo page, they are the same (correct), credentials for database are also correct as website works, admin panel works, but that menu for "Journal2" doesn't work :(

Comment: had u checked the url.php file?

Comment: yep, with this file was everything alright, I have even changed it a bit with your example above but didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Did you properly configure your site for SSL use? Let's go over some things here:

1. Not to sound repetitive, but are you very sure that both your config files are correct? Not sure what you meant before when you said you took "the path for the root" from some page when it's pretty much the url that anyone's going to go visit your site/store. I'm assuming your store/opencart is in it's own folder and not in the root directory, yes? If so:

admin/config.php file should have something like this:

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.yourwebsite.com/opencart/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://www.yourwebsite.com/opencart/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.yourwebsite.com/opencart/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'https://www.yourwebsite.com/opencart/');
```

config.php file should have something like this:

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.yourwebsite.com/opencart/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.yourwebsite.com/opencart/');
```

and by what I recall from past experience that forward slash matters at the end.

2. Also, it matters very much if your url is: yourwebsite.com vs www.yourwebsite.com just to point out that, too.
3. Speaking of which... how about your .htaccess file? That could be a culprit here, too. I'm referring to the htaccess file for your root directory and not opencart's htaccess. That may need to be altered correctly to for https. As an example:

> ```
> Options +FollowSymlinks
>
> RewriteEngine on 
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourwebsite.com/$1 [R,L]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?yourwebsite.com$ 
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/opencart/ 
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /opencart/$1 
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?yourwebsite.com$ 
> RewriteRule ^(/)?$ opencart/index.php [L]
> ```

If you notice here, you need to include the server port and https. So maybe check that, too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The thing is that with config files everything OK, they are properly written including protocols. Still not resolved this issue, but I think that problem is somewhere in the code of Journal2 feature, as with htaccess was everything fine as well.

SSL configured properly - the whole website works, it doesn't show mixed content anywhere and certificate works.

HTTPS protocol for the website was configured in configs, database (website URL) and .htaccess.